# Plugin.Messaging xamarin forms Need to bind an item list to the subject line

Tags: forms, xamarin, binding

it is possible to select an item from a list and bind the result into the subject line in an email using plugin.messaging ?
Thanks in advance !

```
if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail){
       var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
                  .To("whoever@test")
                    .Cc("extra@test")
                  .Subject("{Binding item selected. Title } ")
                  .Body("Well hello there........")
                  .Build();
                emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
            }
```

Comment: That's not really binding, but yes, you can plug in any string variable for the Subject argument

Comment: @Jason . Thanks a lot. that totally works!  **.Subject(" " + feedbackName)**